# How do I pass result of 1st method to second one?

Tags: python, class, object, pycharm

I cannot figure out how do I pass the result of one method to another one. The first method generates new array, filled with numbers in whatsoever size. The second method is supposed to sort all the numbers within the array, which have been previously generated in method no.1. I am getting an error "NameError: name 'value' is not defined". Is this because the list returns None? If so, how do I make it work? I would appreciate any help.

```
        def Display_Details1(self):
            value = []
            num1 = int(input("Select array size: "))
            seed(0)
            for i in range(num1):
                value.append(random.randint(1, 99))
            print(value)
            return value
            print(self.generate)

        def Display_Details2(self):
            value.sort()
            return value
            print(self.sort)
```

Comment: I would recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides and tutorials.

Comment: What will you eventually do with `value`?  You could make it an attribute: `...self.value = value` then `self.value.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a variable from one function as argument to another function can be done like this:

First off, define functions like this:

```
def function1():
    global a
    a=input("Enter any number\t")

def function2(argument):
    print ("this is the entered number - ",argument)
    call the functions like this
```

Then call them like this:

```
function1()

function2(a)
```